# Inside insulation of an exterior wall - insulating on tiles

Tags: drywall, insulation, code-compliance, humidity

I am working on the insulation of my 100 years old house. A full external insulation was too expensive, so I am doing it on a room by room basis.

Now I am planning the bathroom. The current walls are tiled:
[image]

I am planning to insulate over the tiles. The wall layers would look like shown below.

I know, the inside insulation has a potential risk of condensate on the cold surface. But when I enter the layers in an online calculator the overall result looks ok to me:
[image]

The predicted condensate is below what the German building law limits. Additionally the layer connected to the tiles is a woodfibre insulation which should additionally help to absorb humidity and release it when the conditions are dry thus deescalate the condensation issue.

Is there anything else that I should pay more attention to? Should I add some coating to the tiles or add some coating to the gypsum board to reduce the humidity going into the insulation?

Any suggestions what I should change in the setup?

Thanks!

Comment: How effective of an *air* barrier is the thing shown as "vapor retarder" in your image?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - it is an active membrane with a variable humidity transmission resistance. It is "blowproof".